# C# How can I change the value from static class?

Tags: c#

So this is the Program cs. I want to change the value of int in my StaticClass.cs ** I want to delcare a printing sentence " How long do you want me to generate " then change the value of N in StaticClass.

```
class Program
{
    

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Constructor ct = new Constructor(StaticClass.n);
        //ct.xmethod(StaticClass.n);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Here my constructor class. Method of Pascal Triangle

```
class Constructor
{
    
    int[][] triangle = new int[StaticClass.n][];

    public Constructor(int n)
    {
        xmethod(n);
    }

    public void xmethod(int n)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < triangle.Length; row++)
        {

            //Each row is a subarray of length 1 greater than row number
            triangle[row] = new int[row + 1];
            //set the values in a row

            for (int k = 0; k < triangle[row].Length; k++)
            {

                // if not first or last element in the row


                if (k > 0 & k < triangle[row].Length - 1)
                    //set it to sum of the element above it
                    //and the one above and to the left
                    triangle[row][k] = triangle[row - 1][k - 1] + triangle[row - 1][k];

                //otherwise this is an end point, set it to 1
                else


                    triangle[row][k] = 1;

                //display value
                Console.Write(triangle[row][k] + "\t");
            }
            // Finished processing row-send cursor to next line
            Console.WriteLine();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Here my StaticClass for the long of Pascal Triangle

```
class StaticClass
{
    public const int n = 15;

    // I want to change the value of N using the Console Writeline. 

    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n` needs to be updatable then instead of `const` use `static`; but `Console.WriteLine()` is not something you would use to change the value.   You'll need to be more clear about what you want to do.  Do you want someone to input the value of `n` - with  a Console.ReadLine?

So ... from what I gather -- I think you want to change your `Main` to write your question: " How long do you want me to generate " then read the line for user input.  Then print your triangle. Something like :

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How long do you want me to generate? ");
        int inNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Constructor ct = new Constructor(inNum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Then from what I see ... your `Constructor` needs to change:

```cs
    public Constructor(int n)
    {
        triangle = new int[n][];
        xmethod(n);
    }
```

Comment: When I change the value of my int `N` in StaticClass to `0` there's no displaying.

Comment: From the above ... you don't have to use StaticClass at all.  But if you require it. You need to recreate`triagle` each time you change `n`.

Comment: @XmPar - hm. i guess it didn't help you?

Comment: It help jimnkey. I used what u said

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of a const. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants

Use a static property instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members

```
static class StaticClass
{
    public static int n = 15;

    // I want to change the value of N using the Console Writeline. 
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. Then how im gonna change it?

Comment: string val;
      Console.Write("Enter Integer: ");
      val = Console.ReadLine();
      int a = Convert.ToInt32(val);
     StaticClass.n = a;

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("How Tall would you like the triangle to be?");
StaticClass.n = Convert.ToInt32()?`

Comment: You can also use Int32.TryParse() - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0

Comment: Ash, I write your code and there's no error but when im entering a integer nothing show up. I already change the `const` to `static`

Answer (score 0):

Make your public const field a public static property instead:

```
public static int N { get; set; } = 15;
```

Change it like

```
StaticClass.N = 16;
```

You said "change it with WriteLine" - WriteLine outputs things, it doesn't change thing. Perhaps you meant ReadLine:

```
Console.WriteLine("How many levels? ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
StaticClass.N = int.Parse(input);
```

Do please find a better name for StaticClass; classes should be named for what they represent in a more real world sense (like.. Configuration?) not what they are in a C# sense (yes, it's a static class, but it doesn't mean we should call it that)